# Three JS Project Vector3 to Screen

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

I am trying to make a model in which you can select faces ( and they change color/separate from the model). What I am trying to do now is to get a vertice from my selected face and project those coordinates into the screen. I have searched around but most of the questions I've found use deprecated functions. I do realize this question may seem like a duplicate but I haven't found nothing that solves my problem.
I am trying to use the project function from THREE.Vector3 but the coordinates I get are always wrong.

This is the relevant part of the code I am using:

```
var startPoint = mesh.geometry.vertices[selectedPoly.a].clone();
startPoint.project(camera);
startPoint.x = (startPoint.x + 1) / 2 * window.innerWidth;
startPoint.y = ( -startPoint.y - 1)  / 2 * window.innerHeight;
```

I am just trying to reverse what I do to get a mouse click in 3d space. I am probably doing something wrong. Could you please give me a hand?

Comment: check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34214345/extracting-the-2d-screen-position-of-a-3d-point-with-three-js) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27409074/three-js-converting-3d-position-to-2d-screen-position-r69)

Comment: I have seen both and it doesn't work. the coordinates I get are way off.

Comment: Try calling `startPoint.applyMatrix4( mesh.matrixWorld );` before calling `project()`.

Comment: That actually worked. If you want to make an answer explaining the reasoning i'd be glad to accept it